Issue with variable within Sum[] bounds
I have the following sum that starts from a variable lower bound index $n$:
$$\sum _{y=n}^x \frac{n^2! \left(n^2\right)^{-x} \mathcal{S}_x^{(y)}}{\left(n^2-y\right)!}$$
I tried to compute a closed form for it in terms of $n$ and $i$ with the following command:
Sum[((n^2)^-x  (n^2)!  StirlingS2[x, y])/(n^2 - y)!,{y,n,x}]

However, since the lower bound of the sum is variable, it doesn´t output such closed form. Also, if I substitute $n$ by 0, summing with $\{y,0,x\}$ in the above call, it works and provides a sequence that is generated by the value 1, according to $FindSequenceFunction[]$:
$$1.,1.,1.,\frac{3.}{n^4}-\frac{3.}{n^2}+\frac{3. \left(n^2-1.\right)}{n^4}+1.,\frac{n^2!}{n^8 \Gamma \left(n^2-3.\right)}+\frac{1}{n^6}+\frac{7. \left(n^2-1.\right)}{n^6}+\frac{6. \left(n^4-3. n^2+2.\right)}{n^6},\frac{n^2!}{n^{10} \Gamma \left(n^2-4.\right)}+\frac{10. n^2!}{n^{10} \Gamma \left(n^2-3.\right)}+\frac{1}{n^8}+\frac{15. \left(n^2-1.\right)}{n^8}+\frac{25. \left(n^4-3. n^2+2.\right)}{n^8}\cdots$$
With this, how can I compute the original sum with $n$ in the lower bound so that I can find a generating function for $n$ and $x$?

If it works for bounds: {y,0,x} you could sum with this and subtract a sum with bounds: {y,0,n-1}

@daniel-huber I have already tried it, but it does not provide a closed form. It outputs a different expressions for multiple values of $n$, increasing with the sum's upper limit.

There appears to be a closed-form solution for specified values of $n$.
I haven't found the general formula for when $n$ is some positive integer.  Here are the results for $n=1, 2,\ldots,8$.  (Note that there are $n$ terms in each formula so FindSequenceFunction should be given a few more terms than that.)
s[n_, x_] := Sum[((n^2)^-x   (n^2)!   StirlingS2[x, y])/(n^2 - y)!, {y, n, x}]
TableForm[results = Table[{n, 
  FindSequenceFunction[Table[{x, s[n, x]}, {x, n, 10 + 2 n}], x]},
  {n, 1, 8}], TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "Sum"}}]



It's not really an answer.
I think that  does not have finite closed-form expression in terms of very large class of special functions.
f1[n_, x_] := Sum[((n^2)^-x (n^2)! StirlingS2[x, y])/(n^2 - y)!, {y, n, x}]

f2[n_, x_] := -NContourIntegrate[(I (-1 + E^z)^
n (n^2 z)^-x Gamma[1 + n^2] Gamma[1 + x] Hypergeometric2F1[
1, -((-1 + n) n), 1 + n, 1 - E^z])/(
2 \[Pi] z Gamma[1 + n] Gamma[1 - n + n^2]), z \[Element] Circle[{0, 0}, 1]]

f3[n_, x_] := NIntegrate[((-1 + E^E^(I t))^n (E^(I t) n^2)^-x Gamma[1 + n^2] Gamma[
1 + x] Hypergeometric2F1[1, -((-1 + n) n), 1 + n, 
1 - E^E^(I t)])/(2 \[Pi] Gamma[1 + n] Gamma[1 - n + n^2]), {t, 0, 2 Pi}]

With[{n = 3, x = 4}, {f1[n, x] // N, f2[n, x], f3[n, x]}]

(*{0.921811, 0.921811 + 1.27676*10^-15 I, 0.921811 + 1.27676*10^-15 I}*)


Is there any way to get proof of the non-existence of a closed form for it? Also, if a closed form is not available, can we infer its asymptotic growth at $n\to\infty$?

For first  question go to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral. For second question I tried AsymptoticSum and AsymptoticIntegrate Mathematica can't compute.

@Cardstdani Isn't it obvious that for n->infinity (and some constant x) the sum goes to '0'?

@Cardstdani. if $x=n$ then: $$\sum _{y=n}^x \frac{\left(n^2\right)^{-x} n^2! \mathcal{S}_x^{(y)}}{\left(n^2-y\right)!}=\frac{n^{-2 x} \Gamma
\left(1+n^2\right)}{\Gamma \left(1+n^2-x\right)}$$ and $$\underset{{n,x}\to {\infty ,\infty }}{\text{lim}}\frac{n^{-2 x} \Gamma \left(1+n^2\right)}{\Gamma
\left(1+n^2-x\right)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$$
